# Change to a known directory name but unkown absolute path in Python

Tags: python, working-directory

I would like to change the cwd to a specific folder. 
The folder name is known; however, the path to it will vary.

I am attempting the following but cannot seem to get what I am looking for:

```
absolute_path = os.path.abspath(folder_name)
directory_path = os.path.dirname(absolute_path)
os.chdir(directory_path)
```

This does not do what I'm looking for because it is keeping the original cwd to where the .py file is run from. I've tried adding `os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~"))` prior to the first code block; however, it just creates the absolute_path to /home/user/folder_name.

Of course if there is a simple import that I could use, I'll be open to anything.

What would be the correct way to get the paths of all folders with with a specific name?

Comment: How do you get the path to the folder, I'm confused.

Comment: this question needs more clarification before anyone can answer (I dont even understand what you are trying to do...) are you trying to search the whole system for a folder?

Comment: Where *can* the folder be? What happens if the name is "foo", but there are both "/a/foo" and "/b/foo"?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Correct. I am looking for the paths of folders with a specific name

Comment: @DouglasSchuster: The paths to all folders anywhere on the system with a specific name? Or just to those underneath the current working directory? If there are multiple such folders, which on do you want?

Comment: wouldn't traversing through a directory tree and just looking for directories with a specific name work? how is your directory structure?

Comment: @abarnert The paths to all folders on the system with a specific name. I already have something written for getting the correct folder, so that shouldn't be a problem. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: If your system has a search database (Spotlight on Mac, WDS on Windows, `locate` on most Unix-like systems, the various Spotlight-like indexes that your linux or BSD distro may come with), using that instead of scanning the entire drive may be _much_ faster, and will also avoid the problem with directories that you can navigate through but can't read. Of course it will also be platform-specific, and won't work for users who have disabled indexing or whose index is out of date, and so on.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/hz1Veu1s) is some code I found lying around for using Spotlight via PyObjC from a command-line program (one that doesn't already have a run loop, or threads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def find_folders(start_path,needle):
   for cwd, folders, files,in os.walk(start_path):
       if needle in folders:
           yield os.path.join(cwd,needle)

for path in find_folders("/","a_folder_named_x"):
    print path
```

all this is doing is walking down your directory structure from a given start path and finding all occurances of a folder named needle

in the example it is starting at the root folder of the system and looking for a folder named "a_folder_named_x" ... be forwarned this could take a while to run if you need to search the whole system ...

Comment: This also won't work if the directory is not accessible because of permissions (e.g., I may have rx access on `~you/there`, and x access on `~you`, but not r access on `~you`, which means I couldn't _find_ `~you/there` from the top even though I could use it once found). Of course that's not a problem with this code, but a fundamental feature of the POSIX-style permissions and filesystems.

Comment: Thanks, I recognized the runtime as an issue.

Comment: This is mostly important because, on some systems, you have x but not r access to `/home` or `/Users` or the equivalent, meaning you won't even find directories inside your own home this way. And the same may be true for things like `/mnt` or `/Volumes` or the equivalent, meaning you won't find directories on external drives or shares that you mounted. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that `abspath` accepts a *relative pathname* (which might just be a filename), and gives you the equivalent absolute (full) pathname. A relative pathname is one that **begins in your current directory;** no searching is involved, and so it always points to **one** place (which may or may not exist).

What *you* actually need is to search down a directory tree, starting at `~` or whatever directory makes sense in your case, until you find a folder with the requested name. That's what @Joran's code does.